# Как вывести заголовок страницы в хэдере?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. ROR-сайти состоит из layouts и templates. На большинстве сайтов заголовок страницы выводится в шаблоне. Поэтому проблем с выводом заголовка страницы нет

Но на моём сайте требуется выводить заголовок страницы где то в области хэдера. Я поступил следующим образом:
Создал хэлпер:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_page_title
    full_path = request.fullpath

    puts case full_path
    when '/pages/contact'
      page_title = 'Контактная информация'
    when '/blog_articles'
      page_title = 'Блог'
    when '/pages/portfolio'
      page_title = 'Портфолио'
    when '/pages/about'
      page_title = 'О нас'
    when '/'
      page_title = 'Главная'          
    else
      page_title = 'Страница не найдена'
    end  

    return page_title
  end
end
```

и встроил этот хэлпер в шаблон:

```
<div id="content_top">
  <div id="page_title"><%= get_page_title %></div>
</div>
```

Способ рабочий, но не красивый потому что если что-нибудь поменяется в роутинге, то придётся править и хэлпер тоже.

Скажите пожалуйста как решается такая проблема

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то проблема в том, что текст надо выводить в том участке страниц, за который отвечает layout, а сам текст известен только "внутри темплейта".

Для этого есть [yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield).

В layout:

```
<div id="content_top">
  <div id="page_title"><%= yield :title %></div>
</div>
```

В представлении:

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  Мой замечательный заголовок
<% end %>
```